# How to get the return value of wp.media({ frame: 'post' }) in all cases?

Tags: uploads, media, media-library, media-modal

When the user is in an edit.php page or post-new.php, the `wp.media` global is available and I want to use it to open a special insertion view that allows videos.

```
var frame = wp.media({
    frame: 'post'
})

frame.open()
```

I don't seem to get anything out of doing:

```
frame.on('select', function() { console.log('Selected!') })
```

I also know that using `{ frame: 'select' }` as arguments for `wp.media` works with that workflow. But it has embed option. If there's another way to get Image+video I am open to it.

How do I get the return value after the user confirms (supporting the Insert From URL -> paste youtube video URL option) ?